# app crashes after checking network reachability in iphone?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudiosession

i have a mpmovieplayercontroller to play online music and avaudiosession to play the same music at background, when the first time app launches without network access, normally i shows "no internet connection" , when i tried after connecting to internet and playing it shows the error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'
```

my code is here

```
static MPMoviePlayerController *player=nil;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Custom initialization

        [MainViewController  stopStreaming];

        player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://159.253.145.180:7104"]];
        player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
        player.view.hidden = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:player.view];
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player play];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
    NSError *activationErr  = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryErr];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationErr];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    newTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];

    Reachability* reachabile = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.apple.com"];
    NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachabile currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) 
    {
        NSLog(@"not reachable");
        UIAlertView *notReachableAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"NO INTERNET CONNECTION" message:@"This Application Need Internet To Run" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay Buddy" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        notReachableAlert.delegate=self;
        [notReachableAlert show];
        [notReachableAlert release];
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChange:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:player];

    MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22, 320, 200, 15)] autorelease];
    volumeView.center = CGPointMake(152,372);
    [volumeView sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:volumeView];    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

app crashes when i click play button after connecting to internet, any solution?

Comment: You should really use a little extra time for formatting your code. It is close to unreadable. The easier you make it for the reader the more likely you get good and helpful answers.

Comment: There are plenty of possible reasons. Step 1; init your player in viewDidAppear and not already in initWithNib.

Comment: @Till sorry for not properly arranging codes, i think the problem (error) is coming when i added the code AVAudioSession for background activity, actually where did i init the player and its properties?

Comment: Init the player in viewDidAppear (as said before), init the session before initing the player. Basically just do everything you currently do within viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is due to static player. Try using a property of movieplayer

Use:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) MPMoviePlayerController *player;
```

In implementation:

```
@synthesize player = _player;
```

In init:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *plyr = [MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
self.player = plyr;
[plyr relaease];
```

In your code

```
[controller setContentURL:movieURL];
```

Comment: "An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer"

Comment: what is property u using ther?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. The solution that worked for me was remove the instruction

```
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what helped me – initializing with simple init (intead of initWithContentURL), then set movieSourceType and then set contentURL.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be due to a player already existing.

try to add something like this:

```
if (player != nil) {
    [player release];
    player = nil; //i prefer to do both, just to be sure.
}
```

put it after the

```
[MainViewController  stopStreaming];
```

and before the

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://159.253.145.180:7104"]];
```

Comment: sorry, but the problem is still existing,it shows "An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer", this error occurs only when at the first time app launches without network..

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this is right but if you have checked the link

[MPMoviewPlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

which includes the code from apple :

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =
        [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[myView addSubview: player.view];
// ...
[player play];
```

maybe you need to prepareToPlay first and then add it to your view as subview..

i'm not sure but hope this helps..