# suspend the application programmatically if no internet connection iPhone?

Tags: iphone, exit, uiactionsheet

I have a problem which describes here 
[app crashes after checking network reachability in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413433/app-crashes-after-checking-network-reachability-in-iphone)
this problem occurs when app launches at first time, and not yet solved! next solution I found is to close the app if no internet connection found at the first time of launching and tell the user to reopen.

can I use exit(0) if the action sheet ok button pressed, someone says that we can use exit(0); if we have a reason to use that.. any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your code and try to solve crashing problem because Quitting your application  programmatically is a violation of the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27), which usually doesn't  well for getting through the review process:

Comment: thankyou for your feedback, i have tried to solve many times, but not yet found any solution for that, the problem exist when the app launches at the first time without internet! any solution for that..?

Comment: just see my thread, this problem occurs  when the app launches at the first time without internet only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413433/app-crashes-after-checking-network-reachability-in-iphone     hope you will help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) application for your requirement. Provided by APPLE.

In this they have kept it under Application Delegate to be available to all the classes.

The Idea is, you will have to check status of internet connection and if it is not available than you can add a blank view containing information like you are not connected to internet and also make userinteraction to false with your application rootviewcontroller. In this way you will notify user and he/she will not be able to act further.

Again in reversal of this when u are connected to internet you need to remove that view from rootviewcontroller and make userinteraction to true.

Sample image attached herewith.

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: thankyou for your feedback, but the problem is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413433/app-crashes-after-checking-network-reachability-in-iphone , and app crashes when no internet connection detected at the first time of launching only, sorry, am a beginner here and may i ask how will we do user interaction of app to False? any solution

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW27